# convert array to json object in php

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs

Hi i have an array and i need to convert this array to json object

but i need to define a key for each element like my example in the bottom.

my array is:

`$arr= array(["Soap", "25", "10"],["Bag", "100", "15"],["Pen", "15", "13"]);`

what i expect is something like this object to use it  in angular

```
{ "payment":[
{'Name': "Soap",  'Price': "25",  'Quantity': "10"},
{'Name': "Bag",   'Price': "100", 'Quantity': "15"},
{'Name': "Pen",   'Price': "15",  'Quantity': "13"}

]  }
```

how can i do that with php

```
json_encode is not solve my problem
```

Comment: googling your question gives the answer in the first result http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: i know this function but its not solve my problem because   json_encode give just the value read my question again

Comment: where did array come from? Wouldn't be surprised if you didn't strip out available keys already

Comment: this array is came from database

Comment: sorry, i completely missed that you were adding 'name,'price', and 'quantity'. As @charlietfl alluded to, you might be able to use your database library to pull rows out in an associative array. For example, mysqli has [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: no problem thanks the problem is solved by @FuzzyTree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create an associative array

```
$payment = array();

foreach($arr as $row) {
    $payment[] = array(
        'Name' => $row[0],
        'Price' => $row[1],
        'Quantity' => $row[2],
    );
}

print json_encode(array('payment' => $payment));
```